# How can it work static reference to non static with List in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, reference, static, non-static

```
    public String getFullname(){
        return firstName+ " "+ lastName;
    }
    public static void printUser(List<newClass> users){
        for(newClass u: users)
        System.out.println(u.getFullname());    
    }
```

How can it work that getFullname is non static reference but when i use the List as argument, it works.

Of course, I understand it would not work if i write this code like

```
System.out.println(getFullname());
```

Because printUser is static and not getFullname.

Comment: you are calling it through an instance of the class. How else do you think it works? if you don't call it on instance u, it can't make out a method to use.

Answer (score 0):

In first call, u call method from instance of object:
`u.getFullname()`.
In second call, when u try call method
`getFullname()`
it's like `this.getFullname()`.
When static method called, it's like `newClass.printUser(users)` and it's no instance of object was created. So u can't do `this.getFullname()`, because this instance of object wasn't created.
[Static methods vs Instance methods in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-methods-vs-instance-methods-java/)